# How to stream the response using wreck node module?

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement where I need to stream the response from a get request using Wreck node module (cannot use any other node modules as Wreck needs to be used as part of our framework). I went through the documentation but couldn't find any helpful results. Is there a way to using streaming here?

Comment: Perhaps accessing the low-level HTTP objects from Node itself can do the trick. Show us how you handle a request and craft a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Wreck [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wreck#geturi-options):

```
get(uri, [options])

Returns a promise that resolves into an object with the following properties: 
- res - The HTTP Incoming Message object, which is a readable stream that has "ended" and contains no more data to read 
- payload - The payload in the form of a Buffer or (optionally) parsed JavaScript object (JSON).
```

As per the Node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) if readable stream emitted the 'end' event then the data from it has been consumed.

If you really *must* use a stream, I suggest you have a look at [implementing a stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_writable_stream) to basically fake streaming.